# Issue with Swift subclassing a class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, subclass

I have a table view cell create like this where the code crashes on:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! TestedViewCell;
cell.delegate = self;
```

I have the code to create the subclass like so:

```
class TestedViewCell: SwipeTableViewCell
{
    var animator: Any?
}
```

The above lines are in the same file with the kit imported. I then get the error like so:

```
Could not cast value of type 'SwipeCellKit.SwipeTableViewCell' (0x100121a60) to 'app.TestedViewCell' (0x100076f40).
```

Did I subclass it wrong? Thanks.

Comment: is SwipeTableViewCell i sublcass of UItableViewCell??

Comment: It is from this project: https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit

Comment: try to register cell in ViewDidLaod self.tableView.registerClass(TestedViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")

Comment: did you add cell via interface builder and set a class to SwipeTableViewCell instead of TestedViewCell?

Comment: I registered it wrong! Thanks everyone I'll +1 the comments. I did table.register(SwipeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier");
 instead of table.register(TestedViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to register `TestedViewCell` in ViewDidLaod

```
self.tableView.registerClass(TestedViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 1):

From your error

> Could not cast value of type 'SwipeCellKit.SwipeTableViewCell'
>   (0x100121a60) to 'app.TestedViewCell' (0x100076f40).

it is clear that your are trying to Cast SwipeTableViewcell as TestedViewCell. TestedViewCell is subclass of your SwipeTableViewcell . Issue might be in your register cell. You need to register cell in viewDidLoad as

```
self.tableView.registerClass(TestedViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "testedViewCell")
```